# Back up officially purchased app as APK (no root)?

Tags: backup, apk

Version: Android 11

Context: The app has been de-listed from the Play Store but I have the app installed from an official purchase. I want to move the app to another device.

---

I found this [related thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49114/how-do-i-save-purchased-apps-as-apks) but it requires rooting and the "AppMonster" app linked in the accepted answer is no longer available. The discussion also pertains to a very old Android version.

Is there a newer method available without rooting? I don't want to void my warranty just yet.

Comment: When I use [Amaze File manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amaze.filemanager) (also on FDroid) I can use the "App manager" to create a backup of the APK even of paid apps. You should be able to install such an apk on any device. And the app should run if on the device is the Google account registered you bought the app with.

Comment: "*The app has been de-listed from the Play Store [...]*" depending on the situation, [you might still be able to access the app from the Play Store if you have installed it before](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209390/44325).

Comment: @Robert Thanks, that concept worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of [app-based solutions](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_backup) available specialized on this (also some file managers like Amaze mentioned in Robert's comment on your question cover this as well) – or you could simply use [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).

If you're on Linux (Mac or Cygwin should work as well), my tool Adebar has a fitting script in [its `tools/` directory](https://codeberg.org/izzy/Adebar/src/branch/master/tools) which can even deal with split APKs, watch out for `getapk`: when called without parameters it gives you details on its syntax. The script can extract single APKs, or APKs of all system or user-installed apps at once.

Answer (score 2):

I used the [SuperBackup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en_AU&gl=US) app which I had many moons ago and I remembered it had the ability to backup installed apps as APK.

[image: superbackup]

When I backed up the de-listed app, it said along the lines of "APK saved but has no user data because your device is unrooted". I went ahead anyway and installed the APK on another device and logged in with the same Google Account I purchased it with as previously suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Install MiXplorer (https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachments/mixplorer_v6-58-4-api29_b22020920-apk.5532509/) and then follow these steps.

1. Open MiXplorer
2. Press on the three lines (top left)
3. Click on the App category.
4. Press the User App at the top
5. Locate the APK containing your app
6. Copy it to the internal storage/SD Card category
7. Upload it to the cloud in a web browser or the service's official app. (e.g. Google Drive, OneDrive)

[image: User Apps subcategory]
[image: All categories]